# Why the second output of for loop in my code is {20:1}?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn how to write a program that can "make change".

> It should take two numbers as input, one that is a monetary amount
> charged and the other that is a monetary amount given. It should then
> return the number of each kind of bill and coin to give back as change
> for the difference between the amount given and the amount charged.
> The values assigned to the bills and coins can be based on the
> monetary system of any current or former government. Try to design
> your program so that it returns as few bills and coins as possible.

Here is the code.

```
def make_change(given, charged, denominations = [100, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01]):
    assert given >= charged, 'The customer has not given enough!'
    change = {}
    residual = given-charged
    for denomination in denominations:
        amount, residual = divmod(residual, denomination)
        if amount: 
            change[denomination] = int(amount) 
    return change

print(make_change(1000, 575))
print(make_change(1000.84, 575))
{100: 4, 20: 1, 5: 1}
{100: 4, 20: 1, 5: 1, 0.25: 3, 0.05: 1, 0.01: 4}
```

I can't understand the `if amount` statement, what does that mean?
In addition, the first output of divmod(425,100) is (4,25)，and it returns change{100:4}，the second output of divmod(425,20)，it returns (21,5)，so the result should be {100:4, 20:21}, however, the real result is {100: 4, 20: 1, 5: 1}. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: At a first glance, `if amount` ~ `if amound != 0`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please ask only one question at a time. Your secondary question has already been asked here, indirectly: [What is Truthy and Falsy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if amount` is a shortcut for `if amount != 0` here.

Python tries to figure out the "boolean value" of any expression given to `if`
. In case of integers, the boolean value of 0 is False, everything else is True. There is a case to be made that it's better to be explicit and have the if statment written as `if amount > 0`

the first output of `divmod(425, 100)` is indeed `(4, 25)` which is assigned to `amount, residual`. in the line

```
amount, residual = divmod(residual, denomination)
#  ^        ^                ^
# new_amt, new_residual     current_residual,
```

That's another python trick where you can assign multiple values to multiple variable names called [tuple unpacking](https://realpython.com/lessons/tuple-assignment-packing-unpacking/)

after the first loop, the value of residual changes to 25, hence the second loop gets called with `amount, residual = divmod(25, 20)`

Answer (score 0):

The `if amount` statement is testing the value of `amount`: if `amount != 0`, then you add the new item to your dictionary, else (`amount == 0`) do nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by "`some value`"?

Comment: Oh, I just got what you mean, `amount == <not zero>`. You have a comma splice that made it extra confusing. I'll fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The second calculation is not `divmod(425, 20)`, it's `divmod(25, 20)`, because `residual = 25` due to the previous loop.

```
>>> residual = 425
>>> denomination = 100
>>> amount, residual = divmod(residual, denomination)
>>> amount
4
>>> residual
25
```

Answer (score 0):

The program works as you describe it is intended to.

If the needed change is 425, then that should be split into 4 100s, 1 20, and 1 5, like the program does. This will add up to 425 (`4*100 + 1*20 + 1*5`).

4 100s and 21 20s would be 820 change, which is more than 1000 - 575.

Answer (score -1):

`if amount:` is a tricky way to check if `amount` is not 0. It would probably better to explicitly change it to `if amount > 0:`

As far as your question about the output, divmod() returns a tuple of (quotient, remainder). You were correct in saying that divmod(425, 20) = (21, 5) because 425 can be divided by 20 twenty-one times. However you still have to account for the remainder of 5. divmod(5, 5) = (1, 0), meaning that 5 can be divided by 5 one time, with no remainder. Because there is no remainder that's the final answer. Thus, {100: 4, 20: 1, 5: 1}

Comment: `divmod(425, 20)` is a red herring. It's never actually calculated by OP's program, they're just confused.